# Should I add University classes on Linkedin?

Tags: job-search, linkedin

I am a final year data science student. I want to enhance my Linkedin profile which I think it is weak.

We had special courses for data science I took. I was thinking of adding my individual university course papers to Linkedin under Education part.

Do you think is this a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On LinkedIn, there is a section for **Courses** under **Accomplishments**. I recommend you put the courses there. If you published papers, you can put them under **Accomplishments** > **Publications** section.

As a hiring manager, I place a lot more weight on your individual and team projects than just the courses you've taken. The project speak more to your practical hand-ons experience, which is what is needed for your job day-to-day.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with you about the individual projects are important than course papers also I have already a few online courses in Courses  section but in the paper that I want to include, we had a few specific project in the papers. This projects are not huge project that I can add individually but I am thinking might help my job hunting time. I am open all your ideas, this is just my idea want to share

Comment: I've wrote a lot of papers in undergrad and grad, but I only included the ones that were published as noteworthy. If you are picking unpublished papers to include, I would explain why this paper highlights a particular skill. But you may be better not including the paper, because it might just look like you're trying to pad your profile.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, just having taken a class isn't usually a good indication of knowing the subject matter. For example, I took many high voltage courses (and got As in them!) and I remember very little from them - certainly not sufficient to use for anything practical.

So, you can add courses on LinkedIn, but be aware that course experience may not be valued as much as you think. However, it still shows that you have some exposure to the subject matter and may perhaps pick it up quickly in your work.

As jcmack noted, practical hands-on experience is generally more valuable. In some of my hiring experiences, I know that we've overlooked slightly lower grades (than our official/advertised cutoff) in lieu of practical experience earned either through group or hobby projects.